# Proving that: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}+b^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)^n =\sqrt{ab}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, real-numbers, radicals, means

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive reals. Show that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}+b^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)^n =\sqrt{ab}$$

Comment: There are infinitely many possible proofs.

Comment: Could you show us several of them?

Comment: @hkju If that's what you seek, then you should revise the question to state that.

Comment: Even then you should clarify when two solutions are assumed to be "different" to you. Multiplying by some number, doing a simplification and then divising that number again probably doesn't count as "different"? ;)

Comment: The collection of possible proofs of a statement isn't a set, and it shouldn't be thought of as having a cardinality.

Comment: @Qiaochu can you proof that the collection of all possible proofs is not a set?

Comment: Take a standard proof of this statement. Pick a random set $S$ and insert (the irrelevant) statement: "Consider $x \in S$." Since the set of all sets is not a set. This provides a *different* proof for each set $S$ and thus the collection of all possible proofs is not a set.

Comment: However, if you are working within a fixed proof system with a fixed set of accepted symbols (finitely many). Then there are only countably many finite strings over a finite alphabet so there are only countably many proofs within such a fixed system.

Comment: There is a "Community Wiki" designation for questions where many different answers are expected.  But this question does not have that, which I take to mean there will be one "best" answer.

Comment: @Bill thanks. Didn't think of that one. Guess I assumed only those things to be a proof, that can be written down with modern mathematical notation or natural language within one human lifetime ;)

Comment: @example: I don't mean that it's too large to be a set, I mean that it has more structure than a set. It is more like (a rough analogy) a topological space up to homotopy.

Comment: The OP asked for ($\geq2$) different proofs. No need to talk about inaccessible cardinals here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another proof.
Expand in a binomial series, 
$$\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n 
= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (a^{1/n})^k (b^{1/n})^{n-k}.$$ 
Use the de Moivre-Laplace theorem, 
$$ {n\choose k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k} (a^{1/n})^k (b^{1/n})^{n-k} 
\simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(k-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} 
(a^{1/(2\mu)})^k (b^{1/(2\mu)})^{2\mu - k}$$
where $\mu = n/2$ and $\sigma^2 = n/4$. 
Change variables. 
Let $z = (k-\mu)/\sigma$. 
Therefore, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{a b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \,  e^{-z^2/2} \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\sigma z/(2\mu)}.$$
The integral can be done easily enough by completing the square. 
We find
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \,  e^{-z^2/2} \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\sigma z/(2\mu)} 
= \exp \frac{\sigma^2 \log^2(a/b)}{8\mu^2}.$$
But $\sigma/\mu = 1/\sqrt{n}$. 
Therefore, in the limit the integral is unity. 
Thus, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n = \sqrt{a b}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I wanted this approach for my problem. Thanks for noting me that. :)

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Glad to help, Babak. Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following inequality:

$$ \sqrt{xy} \le \frac{x+y}{2} \le \sqrt[x+y]{x^x y^y}$$

The first inequality is straightforward, and the second one can be gotten by

$$ \frac{2}{x+y} = \frac{ x \times 1/x + y \times 1/y}{x+y} \ge \sqrt[x+y]{\frac{1}{x^x y^y}}$$

using the weighted $\text{AM} \ge \text{GM}$.

Setting $x = a^{1/n}$, $y = b^{1/n}$ and taking the $n^{th}$ powers gives us that the limit is $\sqrt{ab}$, by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Nice proof Aryabhata.

Comment: @juantheron: Thanks!

Comment: This, sir, is plain wonderful! :) Thanks a lot for this! :D

Comment: @DomoB: Thanks! And you are welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

An elementary proof. 
We use the Taylor series $e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2)$ and the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n = e^x$.

If $a=b$ the identity is trivial. 
Without loss of generality, assume $0<a<b$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n
&=& b \left(\frac{1+(\frac{a}{b})^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n \\
&=& b \left(\frac{1+e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{a}{b}}}{2}\right)^n \\
&=& b \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{a}{b} + O(1/n^2)\right)^n \\
&=& b \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\ln \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^n + O(1/n).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Therefore, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} b \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\ln \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^n \\
&=& b e^{\ln \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}} \\ 
&=& \sqrt{a b}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Why do you call this elementary?

Comment: @PeterT.off: In what sense is it not?

Comment: Taylor series, $o$ notation. I'd say what is elementary is Aryabhata's proof.

Comment: @PeterT.off: It is fairly typical to label a proof only depending on real analysis "elementary." Notice that I did not claim that the other proofs were not elementary.

Comment: I guess we need to get to an agreement on what elementary means.

Comment: @PeterT.off: Your comments are getting off topic. Instead, why not come up with a "most elementary" proof?

Comment: This was the first way I thought of going. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks, Rob. I was starting to think I was the only one. I like your more symmetric version. (+1) to you.

Comment: @oenamen Basically your proof is a notation variant of what I wrote. Again, Aryabhatas would qualify for "most elementary". I will try and produce another one. (+1), anyways.

Comment: @PeterT.off: I do not use L'Hopital's. I look forward to your next proof.

Comment: @oenamen Yes, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\ln(a/b)+O(1/n^2)\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\ln(a/b)\right)^n+O(1/n).$$ Do you use Taylor on $(1+1/x)^x$ for $x\to \infty $ ?

Comment: @joshua: Just binomial theorem. Note that $ (x + y)^n = x^n + n x^{n - 1} y + \ldots$.

Answer (score 6):

For large $n$,
$$
x^{1/n}=1+\frac1n\log(x)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\left(\frac{\log(a)+\log(b)}{2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^n\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{\log(a)+\log(b)}{2}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{ab}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

You want to prove

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}} \right)^n} = \sqrt {ab} $$

Assume that $a <b$, since $a=b$ will trivially yield the result. We have an indeterminate for of $1^\infty$.

We use

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}} \right)^n} = \exp \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\log \left( {\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}} \right)$$

Then we reduce the indetermination to one of the form $\infty \cdot0$ which is then reduced to one of the form $0/0$, namely:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}} \right)}}{{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Given no assumption is made on $n$ I use L'Hôpital's Rule, from where

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}} \right)^n} = \exp \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a^{1/n}}\log a + {b^{1/n}}\log b}}{{ - 2{n^2}}}\frac{{ - {n^2}}}{{\frac{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}{2}}}$$

$$ = \exp \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a^{1/n}}\log a + {b^{1/n}}\log b}}{{{a^{1/n}} + {b^{1/n}}}}$$

Now this yields

$$\exp \frac{{\log a + \log b}}{2} = \exp \log \sqrt {ab}  = \sqrt {ab} $$

If $n$ is a discrete variable you can use L'Hôpital's discrete analog.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is based on the use of the standard limits $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n(a^{1/n} - 1) = \log a\tag{1}$$ (which can also be taken as a definition of $\log a$ to develop a systematic theory of logarithm and exponential functions) and $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1\tag{2}$$ If $L$ is the desired limit then we have
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^{n}\right\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\log\left(\frac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^{n}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(\frac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n}}{2}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\cdot\dfrac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n} - 2}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n} - 2}{2}\right)}{\dfrac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n} - 2}{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\cdot\dfrac{a^{1/n} + b^{1/n} - 2}{2}\cdot 1\text{ (using (2))}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{n(a^{1/n} - 1) + n(b^{1/n} - 1)\right\}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\log a + \log b)\text{ (using (1))}\notag\\
&= \log\sqrt{ab}\notag
\end{align}
and hence $L = \sqrt{ab}$. Same way we can establish the general formula that if $a_{i}$ are positive then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{a_{1}^{1/n} + a_{2}^{1/n} + \cdots + a_{m}^{1/n}}{m}\right)^{n} = (a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{m})^{1/m}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Paramanand Singh, I like your answer very much. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

Let us first consider that case that $ab=1$, i.e., $b=1/a$. So we want to show find the limit
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac {a^{1/n}+\frac1{a^{1/n}}}2\right)^n = 1. \tag{1}$$
W.l.o.g. we may assume that $a\ge1$. (Otherwise we replace $a$ by $1/a$.)

We can use the fact that for $x\ge1$ we have $2\le x+\frac1x \le 2+(x-1)^2$, which can be verified by a straightforward algebraic manipulation.
(Just notice that $x+\frac1x-2 = \frac{x^2-2x+1}x = \frac{(x-1)^2}x$ and $2+(x-1)^2-x-\frac1x= \frac{x^3-3x^3+3x-1}x = \frac{(x-1)^3}x$.)

So we have
$$1 \le \frac{x+\frac1x}2 \le 1+\frac12(x-1)^2\tag{2}$$
for $x\ge1$.

Using $(2)$ for $x=a^{1/n}$ we get
$$1 \le \left(\frac {a^{1/n}+\frac1{a^{1/n}}}2\right)^n \le \left(1+\frac12(a^{1/n}-1)^2\right)^n \le 1+\frac n2 (a^{1/n}-1)^2.\tag{3}$$
Now it suffices to notice that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac n2 \left(a^{1/n}-1\right)^2 = 
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac 1{2n} \left(\frac{a^{1/n}-1}{1/n}\right)^2 = 0.$$
(Here we are using that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{a^x-1}x = \ln a$, which implies that $(\frac{a^{1/n}-1}{1/n})^2$ is bounded.)

So by squeeze theorem we get that all expressions in $(3)$ converge to $1$ for $n\to\infty$, which proves $(1)$.

---

Once we have $(1)$ we can prove general case using
$$\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}2\right)^n = \sqrt{ab} \left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^{1/n}+\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^{1/n}}2\right)^n.$$
We get the same limit as in $(1)$ with $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$ instead of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \ln [(a^x+b^x)/2].$ Note that $f$ is differentiable everywhere, and $f(0)=0.$ As $x\to 0,$

$$\tag 1\frac{\ln [(a^x+b^x)/2]}{x}=\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} \to f'(0).$$

Computing $f'(0)$ is straightforward: We get $f'(0)= \ln (ab)^{1/2}.$
Taking $x= 1/n$ and using $(1)$ then gives

$$\frac{\ln [(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})/2]}{1/n} = \ln [(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})/2)]^n\to \ln (ab)^{1/2}.$$ Exponentiating gives $[(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})/2]^n \to (ab)^{1/2}$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Elegant answer** Since $(a^h)'= \ln a .a^h$ and $\ln\left(\frac{a^{0}+b^{0}}{2}\right)=0$, **By LHOPITAL RULE we have**

$$\color{red}{
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{a^{h}+b^{h}}{2}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac12\frac{   a^h\ln a+ b^{h}\ln b}{\frac{a^{h}+b^{h}}{2}}=\frac12\ln ab,}$$

Hence , letting $\frac{1}{n}=h$ one has
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}+b^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{
a^{\frac{1}{n}} ++b^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right) =\exp\left(\frac12\ln ab\right) =\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score -1):

We can use standard limits $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^\frac1x =e$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log a$ to obtain

$$\left(\frac{a^{1 / n}+b^{1 / n}}{2}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{a^{1 / n}-1+b^{1 / n}-1}{2}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac{a^{1 / n}-1+b^{1 / n}-1}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{a^{1 / n}-1+b^{1 / n}-1}}\right]^{\frac12\left({\frac{a^{1 / n}-1}{\frac1n}+\frac{b^{1 / n}-1}{\frac1n}}\right)}\to [e]^{\frac12(\log a +\log b)}=\sqrt {ab}$$