# How to find the limit of $\left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)^x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit of

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)^x.$$

I've calulated the limit on Mathamatica and it equals $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$.

But I've tried more to reach that value but failed .

This is what I've done:

\begin{align*}
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)^x & =\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{x \ln \left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)} \\
& =\exp\left({\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x \ln \left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)}\right) \\
& =\exp\left({\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x \ln \left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)}\right) \\
& =\exp\left({\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)
\end{align*}

Also,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\ln \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}}+b^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\right) &=\frac{\frac{\frac{-a^{1 / x}}{2 x^2}-\frac{-b^{1 / x}}{2 x^2}}{\frac{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
&=\frac{-a^{1 / x}-b^{1 / x}}{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}},\end{align*}
so the original limit is $$\exp\left({\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-a^{1 / x}-b^{1 / x}}{a^{1 / x}+b^{1 / x}}}\right)$$

and stopped here!

How can I reach the value $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$?

Comment: https://youtu.be/RoqErc0NKmE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}+b^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)^n =\sqrt{ab}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130497/proving-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-fraca-frac1nb-frac1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D(%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%2Bb%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%7D%7B2%7D)%5Ex%24&p=1). There's also several other duplicates, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [I need a help with this limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{a^{1/x}+b^{1/x}}{2}\right)^x = \sqrt{ab}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819719), [find a limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}}{2}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564755), etc.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating ths question. but the answer become clear enough