# Evaluating a limit involves parameters

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a,b>0$:
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {({a^n} + {b^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

At first look, it seemed simple, yet I couldn't evaluate it.
Maybe Squeeze Thm?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Hopital's rule?

Comment: Squeeze theorem works fine here. Suppose without loss of generality $a \geqslant b$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/130537/8581) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/264223/8581)

Comment: Yes, I am allowed

Comment: @B.S., From the second link:  
$${\left( {\frac{A}{2}} \right)^x} = \frac{{\log (A)}}{{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
Why is it true?

Comment: @SuperStamp: Great Andrea used the Hopital's rule for solving it. In fact set $y=(\frac{A}2)^x$ and then take $\log$ from both sides and...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Take the largest out of the parentheses (say $a>b$). You then have $a(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where $x<1$. At this point, you get the limit easily.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: the answer is $a$? Hence $max(a,b)$. Right?

Comment: @SuperStamp. As far as I know, you are right.