$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{2^x + 3^x + 5^x}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$ without L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor approximations
I was recently nerd-sniped by the limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{2^x + 3^x + 5^x}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{x}\,.
$$
The challenge is to do it without using L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor approximations (or any other sufficiently advanced tools). The only idea I have so far is to try to squeeze the limit. Applying the AM-GM inequality yields a lower bound of $\sqrt[3]{30}$ (which is actually the value of the limit), but I can only produce a loose upper bound of $5$ which isn't good enough.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Apply the same for negative $x$ and you'll get the upper bound.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. @IvanNeretin's tip is probably the quickest option given what you've already done, but you might like this approach, depending on what tools you consider advanced.

@IvanNeretin I might be missing something here, but surely establishing an upper bound for $x > 0$ and a lower bound for $x < 0$ does not establish either one-sided limit by squeeze theorem, right?

Various solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397376/42969

@TheoBendit Of course. This is only made useful by the implicit knowledge that the two-sided limit exists in the first place (which we did not prove).

I wonder why the downvote? Are we just discouraging new users for fun now?

Thanks for the hints, I managed to do it! My apologies for not finding the duplicate question earlier
